# Custom validator in Angular 13 which forces to check at least one checkbox is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

I'm using Angular 13 and I'm trying to apply a custom validator for some of the fields of a form.
Lets say I have:

- Input 1
- Input 2
- Checkbox 1
- Checkbox 2
- Checkbox 3

in which I bind an ngForm and a bidirectional ngModel in every field:

```
<form class="flex-col text-center" #inspectionForm="ngForm">
...
...
...
 <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
    <input class="form-control" type="text " [(ngModel)]="inspectionService.checkbox1" name="checkbox1" required />
 </div>
</form>
<button [disabled]="!inspectionForm.form.valid" type="button" class="btn bg-primary-tb text-white mt-3 col-4" (click)="submit();">Continue</button>
```

I want to apply the validator **to the checkboxes only**. It must force the user **to check at least one.**

The point is to disable a button by using `[disabled]="!inspectionForm.form.valid"`

This is essencially my code in the `form.component.ts`:

```
  @ViewChild('inspectionForm') inspectionForm ?: NgForm;

      atLeastOneValidator(checkboxes: string[]): ValidatorFn{
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      for(let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        if(this.inspectionForm!.form.get(checkboxes[i])?.value === true) return null;
      }
      return  { 'atLeastOne': true };
    }
  }



  ngOnInit(): void {
    let checkboxes = ['checkbox1', 'checkbox2', 'checkbox3']; // Checkboxes' names

    checkboxes.forEach(item => {
      this.inspectionForm?.form.controls[item].setValidators([this.atLeastOneValidator(checkboxes)]);
      this.inspectionForm?.form.controls[item].updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: true});
    })
```

but it doesn't work. I don't know what am I doing wrong or if I skipped something

Answer (score 1):

A multi-control validatino should be made on the form, not on a control.

```js
form = this.formBuilder.group({ /* ... */ }, [atLeastOne(['cb1'])]);

// Some file somewhere

export function atLeastOne(boxNames) {
  return function(form) {
    const boxes = Object.entries(form.controls)
      .filter(([key]) => boxNames.includes(key))
      .map(([, v]) => v);

    const valid = boxes.some(box => !!box.value);

    return valid ? null : { 'atleastone': true };
  }
}
```

Comment: Really it's not necesary, you can "reach" the "parent FormGroup"  from the "control". The only is to check when change any element to call to updateValueAndValidity for the rest of controls.

Comment: Thing is that my FormGroup is already created by using `#inspectionForm="ngForm"`, I also bind data coming from the backend through ngModel, so I just wanted to add a validator to those especific fields only. I've been checking setValidators method and It doesn't seem wrong, based on what I saw on other questions

Comment: @Eliseo that's why you do it on the form itself, to avoid all of what you're explaining.

Comment: @Kalima I am giving you the reactive approach because the template driven one (ngModel) is way heavier. [Take a look](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-custom-validators-to-template-driven-forms) for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "this" has no value into your function `atLeastOneValidator`

You can use `bind(this)` (it's javascript [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind))

```
this.inspectionForm?.form.controls[item].setValidators(
     [this.atLeastOneValidator(checkboxes).bind(this)]);
```

but be sure you get the form  inside your function atLeastOneValidator

Or "reach" the form using control.parent

```
atLeastOneValidator(checkboxes: string[]): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      const parent = control.parent as FormGroup;
      if (!parent)
        return null;
      const success = checkboxes.reduce((a,b)=>a || parent.get(b).value,false);

      return success ? null : { atLeastOne: true };
    };
  }
```

But be carefull, a FormControl only is checked if valid or not when have a input relationated and the input change or when we call manually to updateValueAndValidity.

So, we can create a function

```
  updateValueAndValidity(...checkboxes:string[])
  {
    checkboxes.forEach((x) => {
      this.form.get(x).updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent:false})
    });
  }
```

And call in .html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checkbox1" 
      (change)="updateValueAndValidity('checkbox2','checkbox3')"/>
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checkbox2" 
      (change)="updateValueAndValidity('checkbox1','checkbox3')"/>
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checkbox3" 
      (change)="updateValueAndValidity('checkbox1','checkbox2')"/>
</form>
```

Or subscribe to valuesChanges

Comment: Hey Eliseo thanks for answering! I've taken your solution as reference, so I've tried with this:

ngOnInit(): void {
    let checkboxes = ['ocr', 'anomalyDetection', 'metrics', 'wiresInspection', 'other' ];

    checkboxes.forEach(item => {
      this.inspectionForm?.form.controls[item].setValidators([this.atLeastOneValidator(checkboxes)]);
    })
    
    this.inspectionForm?.valueChanges!.subscribe(x => {
      console.log("change");
      this.inspectionForm!.form.controls[x].updateValueAndValidity();
  })

But it isn't working, I can't see any "change" in console